# iOS CoreBluetooth print CBService and CBCharacteristic

Tags: ios, swift, printing, core-bluetooth

I am using Swift to develop a iOS application to integrate bluetooth printer to print out information. I have used CoreBluetooth framework but can't know which service, characteristic I can writevalue to print out

```
//find CBService
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
    //println("CBPeripheralDelegate didDiscoverServices")

    for service in peripheral.services {

        println("Service: Discover service \(service)")
        println("Service: UUID \(service.UUID) ")

        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service as! CBService)

    }
}

//find CBCharacteristics
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {

    //if service.UUID == CBUUID(string: "18F0"){
        for characteristic in service.characteristics {

            let chara: CBCharacteristic? = characteristic as? CBCharacteristic
            println("Char: service \(service.UUID) Discover char \(chara)")
            println("Char: UUID \(chara!.UUID)")

            peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(chara)

            /*
            println("0")

            switch chara!.UUID {

            case CBUUID(string: "2AF1"):
                println("1")

                var rawArray:[UInt8] = [0x01];
                let data = NSData(bytes: &rawArray, length: rawArray.count)

                peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: chara, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)

            default: println("")
            }
            */
        }
    //}

}
```

and the system display result like below:

Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID Battery 
Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID 1803 
Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID 1802 
Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID 1811 
Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID 1804 
Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID 18F0 
Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID Device Information 
Service: Discover service 
Service: UUID E7810A71-73AE-499D-8C15-FAA9AEF0C3F2

Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID Battery Level
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A06
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A06
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A47
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A46
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A48
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A45
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A44
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2A07
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2AF1
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID 2AF0
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID System ID
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID Manufacturer Name String
Char: Discover char 
Char: UUID BEF8D6C9-9C21-4C9E-B632-BD58C1009F9F

can any bluetooth expert can guide me, thanks

Comment: You will need information from the printer vendor as to how to interface with their product.  My guess would be that you write to characteristic `BEF8D6C9-9C21-4C9E-B632-BD58C1009F9F` as that is the only non-standard one

Comment: Like Paulw11. Look also at `properties` of your `CBCharacteristic` that should give you if you can only read them or write, notify, etc.

Comment: @Paulw11 i try to modify to use "BEF8D6C9-9C21-4C9E-B632-BD58C1009F9F", and var rawArray:[UInt8] = [0x01];        let data = NSData(bytes: &rawArray, length: rawArray.count)                peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: chara, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)

Comment: @Paulw11 but, not work, have any chance my writeValue used wrong or have to modify any code?

Comment: @KevinChang did you try Lite blue app? It will guide you through the characteristics and will show you the ones you can write

Answer (score 5):

**Short version**
Just write to any non-standard Service with a Characteristic with Properties `Write` or `WriteWithoutResponse`. Be sure to write less than 20 bytes the first time to avoid passing the buffer limit.

**Long version:**
I had the same problem with a bluetooth thermal printer (QSPrinter 5801 Bluetooth LE) that had exactly the same services and characteristics of the device from this question.
I found out that the:

Service `18F0` with characteristic `2AF1` had property `WriteWithoutResponse`

Service `E7810A71-73AE-499D-8C15-FAA9AEF0C3F2` with characteristic 
 `BEF8D6C9-9C21-4C9E-B632-BD58C1009F9F` had properties `Read+Write+Notify+Indicate`

(where `Write` means `Write with response`).

This is the official list of properties of a Characteristic:

```
Broadcast = 0x01,
Read = 0x02,
WriteWithoutResponse = 0x04,
Write = 0x08,
Notify = 0x10,
Indicate = 0x20,
AuthenticatedSignedWrites = 0x40,
ExtendedProperties = 0x80
```

A property can have multiple values by using bit field multiplication.
For example properties 0x30 is 00110000 in binary which means Notify+Indicate. You need to get the binary number (8 bits) and place the binary bits from right to left on the values list from top to bottom:

```
0 Broadcast
0 Read
0 WriteWithoutResponse
0 Write
1 Notify
1 Indicate
0 AuthenticatedSignedWrites
0 ExtendedProperties
```

In the end I discovered I could write to either of characteristic successfully by using:

```
let bytesToPrint: [UInt8] = [27, 64, 10, 10, 10, 99, 105, 97, 111, 10, 10, 10]
let data = Data(bytes: bytesToPrint)
```

`//Using Characteristic 2AF1 with Properties WriteWithoutResponse
peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)`

`//Using Characteristic BEF8D6C9-9C21-4C9E-B632-BD58C1009F9F with Properties Write
peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)`

**The problem was that I was sending too many bytes of data at the same time.** Each bluetooth low energy device has a different buffer size. I heard of people finding the buffer limit of a device to be 20, 40, 100, 400 bytes.
In my case the limit was 100 so as soon as I started to send less than 100 bytes the bluetooth device reacted correctly.
My advice is to try to send less than 20 bytes to start with and once it works you can increment the bytes sent until it stops working and you'll know you've reached the buffer limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the light blue app (iOS)and one by one you’ll find the right characteristic to write. It has options to write values from the app

[image: Light Blue]

Comment: As you can see from the Question the Characteristics had been already found programmatically. As I explained in my answer the problem was actually writing too many bytes and passing the buffer limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this found on Github in working condition(BLEDemo), while I was working on Bluetooth printer

```
let BLEService = "DFB0"
let BLECharacteristic = "DFB1"
```

// MARK: CBPeripheralDelegate Methods

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        
        print("Service found with UUID: " + service.uuid.uuidString)
        
        //device information service
        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "180A") {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
        
        //GAP (Generic Access Profile) for Device Name
        // This replaces the deprecated CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString
        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "1800") {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
        
        //Bluno Service
        if (service.uuid.uuidString == BLEService) {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
        
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    //get device name
    if (service.uuid.uuidString == "1800") {
        
        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            
            if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A00") {
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Found Device Name Characteristic")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    if (service.uuid.uuidString == "180A") {
        
        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            
            if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A29") {
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Found a Device Manufacturer Name Characteristic")
            } else if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A23") {
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Found System ID")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    if (service.uuid.uuidString == BLEService) {
        
        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            
            if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BLECharacteristic) {
                //we'll save the reference, we need it to write data
                mainCharacteristic = characteristic
                
                //Set Notify is useful to read incoming data async
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                print("Found Bluno Data Characteristic")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```